# My Rvest scraper is way too slow

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have created an Rvest scraper that scrapes a job listing site. Unfortunately, it takes for ever to loop through just 100 pages. Is there any quick fix to make this faster? Below is the basic structure I'm using

```
for(i in beginning:end){
  url <-  read_html(paste0("https://www.jobsite.com",links[[1]][i]))
  address[[i]] <-   html_nodes(x = url, css = selector_name) %>%
    html_text()
  employer[[i]] <- employer[[i]][3]
  rating[[i]] <-   html_nodes(x = url, css = selector_rating) %>%
    html_attr("data-jobsite") %>% as.numeric()
  rating[[i]] <- rating[[i]]*(10/6)
  rating[[i]] <- round(rating[[i]])
  rating[[i]] <- ifelse(length(rating[[i]]) == 0, 1, rating[[i]])
  title[[i]] <-   html_nodes(x = url, css = ".xsmall-10") %>%
    html_text()
  title[[i]] <- stri_replace_all_fixed(title[[i]], "            ", "")
  title[[i]] <- stri_replace_all_fixed(title[[i]], "        ", "")
  title[[i]] <- stri_replace_all_fixed(title[[i]], "\r\n", "")
  dd[[i]] <-   html_nodes(x = url, css = ".item-price")%>%
    html_text()
}
```

Comment: Don't use a `for` loop, use `lapply`. If you are going to use a `for` loop, preallocate a vector of the appropriate size (which is hard in this case). And [don't use regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4497050).

Comment: It is slow because you have to download the page every time, one at a time. If you are comfortable with python, I'd like to suggest using aiohttp and asyncio. It's amazingly fast because you can request for many pages simultaneously. https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html. R was designed to be single threaded -- parallelization is possible (see package `future`) but complicated.

Comment: How long is forever?

Comment: You could try this: https://github.com/jeroenooms/curl/blob/master/examples/sitemap.R

Comment: thanks everyone, very helpful, a friend of mine has also suggested to use an HTML DOM parser instead?

Comment: There is now a multi-threaded scraper for R. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352711017300110

Comment: I reimplemented my rvest code in python with aiohttp following the tutorial suggested by @Jean, but ended up just being blocked by the site. Rvest being very slow and working sequentially instead of parallelly actually seems to be an advantage, because it comes closer to human behavior. There's no point in parallelizing and then adding delays again for not being blocked.

Comment: It is highly recommended to even build upon rvest's 'slowness' further: Consider using the R package `polite` (https://github.com/dmi3kno/polite) to follow "responsible web etiquette" while scraping.